# The button does not redirect to the link if I make a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a button on a form that redirects the page to another web, once the data is validated. The href of the button has information only if those data are validated, otherwise it will be null.

The problem is that, even though everything is running normally, for the user to be redirected to the page, two clicks are needed on the button, and I do not know why.

I pass the format of the html form, the function that validates the data and then the part where the data is captured and the href of the button is filled. All this in a very summarized way with the relevant things.

**FORM HTML:**

```
    <form id="formTarjeta" class="formPayu" onsubmit="return registroCompraTarjeta()">

        <p><strong>Dirección de envío</strong></p>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon">

                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>

                </span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroDireccionTarjeta" name="registroDireccionTarjeta" placeholder="BUSQUE y SELECCIONE su dirección" required>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default backColor btnPayu" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> PROCESANDO">CONFIRMAR DATOS</a>

</form>
```

**VALIDATION FUNCTION IN JS**

```
function registroCompraTarjeta(){

    var direccionTarjeta = $("#registroDireccionTarjeta").val();

    if(direccionTarjeta == ""){ 

        swal('WARNING', 'warning');

        return false; }

  return true;

}
```

**DATA CAPTURE AND CHANGE HREF BUTTON**

```
$("#formTarjeta").on('click','.btnPayu',function(e){

    if (registroCompraTarjeta() == true) {

         //CAPTURE DATA FORM AND CREATE AN ARRAY TO SEND BY AJAX

        if(...){

            $.ajax({

                url:"ajax/cart.ajax.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: array,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(response){

                    $('.btnPayu').attr('href', response);
                    $('.btnPayu').on('click', function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.button('loading');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                           $this.button('reset');
                       }, 4000);
                    });

                }

            })

        } else {
                ... 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you need an href in your <a> tag?

Comment: @kattapillar No. The href, as I explain, is empty, but a href is assigned in the ajax response. Everything works fine, I just need to click twice to redirect me to the href link

Comment: What is `type="submit"` for? The `type` attribute is for buttons and inputs, it has no meaning for anchors.

Comment: @Barmar My mistake when copying the code. There I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the AJAX request is running asynchronously. It doesn't change the `href` until after the click event has been processed completely, so it can't affect how that click is processed.

Instead of changing the `href`, assign to `window.location` to redirect to the new page.

```
$.ajax({

  url: "ajax/cart.ajax.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: array,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    window.location = response;
  }
})
```